# Git - How can I recover a git repository to a normal directory?

Tags: git

How can I recover a git respository to a normal directory? I made some tests but I only get delete the files.

Explaining better, I want to remove git from the directory, keeping the files without git versioning. "transform" git directory to a normal directory.

Comment: Do you want to replace the data in the directory with the data in the repository? In that case, you could use `git reset --hard`.

Comment: That's a *Clone,* AFAICT.

Comment: This is the case where multiple answers are correct because the question is unclear and we don't know what exactly the OP wants...

Comment: @RobertHarvey which tests did you make? please describe them.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "which tests did you make."  What you're describing is a simple GIT CLONE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you’re on the branch with the file versions you desire.
2. Delete the .git folder
3. Delete the .gitignore file (if one exists)

Comment: I did this, but after unstage the files. The files were deleteds. I going to test without unstage the files. Thank you!